# Authentication or effective use of cookie file captured using phantomjs

Tags: cookies, authorization, phantomjs

I have few automations to do in `"http://testdomain.com/web/abd/efg"` using phantomjs. But before doing that I need to login using `"http://testdomain.com/"` which contains the username and password field(in this page) using the js script.
**Note** -  I can only go to this `http://testdomain.com/web/abd/efg` url only after logging in to this `http://testdomain.com/`

In the js script I gave

```
page1.settings.userName = 'username';
page1.settings.password = 'password';
```

and also with

```
page.customHeaders={'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password')};
```

as suggested in http://darrendev.blogspot.jp/2013/04/phantomjs-post-auth-and-timeouts.html
for opening `http://testdomain.com/web/abd/efg` url. But nothing worked.

I also captured the cookies during login using `"http://testdomain.com/"` by giving `--cookies-file=./cookies.txt` in the commandline.
Can I use this captured cookie to login and move to this url `"http://testdomain.com/web/abd/efg"`?

Any hint or help is appreciable.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I'm having the same trouble.  I can login using one script, but when I attempt to use the same cookies file in another script I find that I'm not logged in anymore.